# Modifying the integer at the end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am in need of your assistance,

What I need is a javscript function that would accomplish one of two things:

Firstly, if given a string, ie. `var x = "filenumber"` the function when called, would process the string and add a -2 to the end of it, resulting in `var x = "filenumber-2"` if the -2 does not exist on the end of the string.

Secondly, if the given value, `var x is already = "filenumber-2"` then take the number at the end of the string and increment it by 1, resulting in `var x = "filenumber-3".` and so fourth incrementing the number every single time after that, if the function is called again.

Here is the concept markup:

```
<DOCYTPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){

var x = document.getElementById('input').value

1.) if x doesnt already have the -2 at the end of the string then add it:

document.getElementById('output').value = x + "-2"


2.) else, the function recognizes that it does and the result of the output is

x-2 + 1

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<br>
<input type="text" id="output"/>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="test()" value="test"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're forgetting the `!` in the doctype declaration btw.

Comment: It's not a homework question at all. Im doing some DB prep work in the backend prior to adding new files. Some of the file names will be date specific and must be distinguished by the integers. That part just seems like pure rocket science to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short 'n sweet:

```
x = 'filenumber-4';
x = x.replace(/^(.+?)(-\d+)?$/, function(a,b,c) { return c ? b+(c-1) : a+'-2'; } );
```

Comment: Wow that is really short and sweet. Its seems so complex to me. I knew I should have taken that extra algebra class in high school. Nonetheless its pure rocket science and genious! Thanks for everyones help!

Comment: You're welcome -- short as it is, it was fun to write. Can you figure out why and how it works?